# AssertionError: Mismatch between dataset size and units in output layer

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I want to do a NN classification using scikit-neuralnetwork , I have 5 classes, so in the output layer , I have units=5 ibut I am getting this error: Mismatch between dataset size and units in output layer,
I reshaped my y_train and applied "Sigmoid" function to the output layer according to the documentation:
http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide_model.html#classification

> If you want to do multi-label classification, simply fit using a y array of integers that has multiple dimensions, e.g. shape (N, 3) for three different classes. Then, make sure the last layer is Sigmoid instead.

y_train shape is : (2115, 5)
X_train shape is : (2115, 343)
This is the code:

```
import sknn.mlp as mlp
from sknn.mlp import Classifier
ip_layer = mlp.Layer('Sigmoid', units=1)
hidden_layer = mlp.Layer('Tanh', units=100)
op_layer = mlp.Layer('Sigmoid', units=5) 

nn = Classifier(
    [ip_layer, hidden_layer, op_layer],
    n_iter=10000
)
nn.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 1):

The input layer has one unit.

If you set `ip_layer = mlp.Layer('Sigmoid', units=343)` it should work.